# Missing statement block

Tags: powershell

I am learning powershell at the moment, and the company i work has asked me to make something.
It is a script that reads the executionpolicy and writes to a file if the status has bypass.
For some reason, i keep getting a Missing Statement Block at the script. What am i doing wrong? I hope somebody can help me with this question.

```
If ((Get-DAConnectionStatus).Status -eq 'ConnectedRemote') -or ((Get-VpnConnection -AllUserConnection | Where {$_.Name -eq 'Always On VPN Device Tunnel versie 1.0'}).connectionStatus -eq 'Connected'))
{
   
    If ((Get-DAConnectionStatus).Status -eq 'ConnectedRemote')
    {
        
        If (Test-path "I:\APPDATA\Powershell\ExecutionPolicy\Log")
        {
            $ExecutionPolicyStatus | Out-File -FilePath $Logbestand -Append
                        
            Delete
                       
        } Else {
            Write-Output "Geen verbinding naar I schijf"
        }
    } Else {
        Write-Output "Directacces verbinding niet gevonden"
    }
} Else {
    Write-Output "Status is gelijk aan bypass"
}
```

Comment: It seems that the last line `}Else{ Write-Output "Status is gelijk aan bypass" }` comes after all the brackets were closed. So you closed the brackets 2 times, but opened only once.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statement has a wrong amount of brackets, you are missing at least one.
Try this:

```
if (((Get-DAConnectionStatus).Status -eq 'ConnectedRemote') -or ((Get-VpnConnection -AllUserConnection | Where {$_.Name -eq 'Always On VPN Device Tunnel versie 1.0'}).connectionStatus -eq 'Connected')) {
# the rest of the code
}
```

Or to make your code even more readable, you could use some variables:

```
$isConnected = (Get-DAConnectionStatus).Status -eq 'ConnectedRemote'
$isConnectedViaVPN = (Get-VpnConnection -AllUserConnection | Where {$_.Name -eq 'Always On VPN Device Tunnel versie 1.0'}).connectionStatus -eq 'Connected'

if ($isConnected -or $isConnectedViaVPN) {
# the rest of the code
}
```